# Angular 4 HttpClient Authentication

Tags: angular

I have seen many examples using basic authentication with username/password.

For Example:

[Angular 4.3 HTTPClient Basic Authorization not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894628/angular-4-3-httpclient-basic-authorization-not-working)

However, **does Angular 2/4/5/6 support [Certificate-Based Authentication](https://www.globalsign.com/en-sg/blog/what-is-certificate-based-authentication/)** for HttpClient requests? (Not user authentication)

Did not find anything in Angular docs.

Comment: I think you don't understand how certificate based authentication works. The server should request a client certificate, then the browser will show a popup on the client to provide the certificate. There is nothing that needs to be done in angular, at least not for providing the certificate.

Comment: @CornelC Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I am talking about the Http request between Angular HttpClient and REST API. The certificate will be self signed, and stored in a keystore file which is placed where the Web is running. Whenever Angular HttpClient makes post/get requests to REST API, the requests would need to be authenticated by passing along the certificate which is verified by REST API. The concept is similar to SSL connection for IBM MQ client/server, if you know what I mean.

Comment: I know, but that doesn't work. You cannot send client certificates from javascript. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033824/sending-client-certificate-via-javascript