# Fetch data in Vue.js using certificates

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, https, axios

I'm trying to connect to an endpoint url that uses self-signed certificates on AWS from Vue in order to trigger a Lambda. Currently, I'm using Axios to do so and it works when I try to fetch any url that doesn't requires a certificate, for example OpenWeatherAPI. Alongside Axios, I'm using the module `https` and `fs` to read the certificate in my machine and create an object to send it with Axios. This method has worked in the past when I did the same in Qwik and React as part of a demo, and that is what I'm currently doing with Vue.
I also thought maybe Nginx would help but I'm not sure, I've never worked with Nginx in past.

Is there's a better way to send certificates from Vue.js when fetching any endpoint?

> **Note: With Vue I'm using Typescript.**

This is the code:

```
const url = "https://page.with.certs.org/metadata/123-00-0000?type=status"
const url_weather = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=api&q=city"
const cert='/home/my/certificates/crt.pem'
const key='/home/my/certificates/key.pem'
const headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
};

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        cert: fs.readFileSync(cert),
        key: fs.readFileSync(key),
        passphrase: "password-here"
});

data() {
        const data = {
            msg: ""
        }
        const weather_data = async () => { //weather page
            const data = await axios.get(url_weather, { headers })
            console.log(data.data[0].description)
            return data.data[0].description;
        }
        const payload = async () => { //page with certs
            try {
                const data = await axios.get(url, { httpsAgent, headers })
                console.log(data.data.payload)
                data.msg = data.data.payload
            } catch (error: any){
                if (error.response.code == 404){
                    console.log("Error")
                }
                console.log(error.response.data.payload.error)
                data.msg = error.response.data.payload.error
            }
        }
        
    return { weather_data, data };
}
```

Also, I don't know why the module `fs` is complaining about not reading the certs, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'readFileSync')` because the certificates exists.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Two things : 1 `fs` is a nodejs/server concept, vue is a client framework.  The client can't use `fs`. That would be very insecure to allow a javascript to just read any file on your system.  2 certificate exchange happens higher up the chain in the browser itself and can't be be added through javascript on the client.  If it's been selected in the browser, it will automatically be sent. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033824/sending-client-certificate-via-javascript).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I don't know why, my browser isn't sending the certificates (even though I have the certificates added to my browser) when trying to connect. I'll definitely try to use Nginx, thanks again.